# How to change this Runge-Kutta method implementation from first order ode solver to system of ODEs solver?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python, runge-kutta-methods

I implemented 4-step Runge-Kutta method (k1..k4) ODE solver for a function  $u'(x) = f(x,u(x))$ with initial condition $u(x_0) = u_0$

But it solves just ODEs of the first order. How could I change the code, so that it also takes ODEs of higher order? ${\bf u}'(x)={\bf f}(x,{\bf u}(x))$ with initial condition ${\bf u}(x_0)= {\bf u}_0$? All as vectors here not scalars.

Here is the code for my solution, which takes first order ODEs:

```
def euler(f, x, y, h):
    yn = y + h*f(x,y)
    xn = x + h
    return xn, yn

def rk4(f, x, y, h):
    k1 = h*f(x,y)
    k2 = h*f(x+(1/2)*h,y+(1/2)*k1) 
    k3 = h*f(x+(1/2)*h,y+(1/2)*k2)
    k4 = h*f(x+h,y+k3)
    yn = y + ((1/6)*(k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4))
    xn = x + h
    return xn, yn

def integrate(method, f, t0, y0, tend, h): # Depending on the 'method' (euler or rk4) this method solves the ode f)
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0 
    while (t < tend):
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y = method(f, t, y, h)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)

#def f1(t, y):   # this is an 1st order ODE
    #return (t*y) + t

# Usage example
xv, yv = integrate(method=rk4, f=f1, t0=0, y0=2, tend=1, h=0.5)
yv[-1] # Output: 6.15203857421875
```

Is there a solution, to make this work also for a given system of ODEs? (dynamically, without knowing the input ODE if it's 1st or higher order)for example this one: 
$$u''(x)+u(x)+u(x)^3 =0 ~~{\rm with}~~ u(0)=u'(0)=0 $$
or this one:
$$u_1'(x) = 98u_1(x) + 198u_2(x) ~~{\rm and}~~ u_2'(x) = −99u_1(x) − 199u_2(x) \\~~{\rm with}~~ u_1(0) = 1 ~~{\rm and}~~ u_2(0) = 0$$

EDIT:

changed the code to this now, to try if the 1st given example 2nd order ODE works:

```
def f(t,y):
    return np.array([ y[1], -y[0]-(y[0])**3 ])

Y0 = np.array([0.0,0.0])

xv, yv = integrate(method=rk4, f=f, t0=0.0, y0=Y0, tend=100.0, h=h)
print("[ %20.15f, %20.15f]"%(yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]) )
print(yv)
```

but I get an output consisting of 0 vectors like this:

```
[    0.000000000000000,    0.000000000000000]
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: This seems to be more a question about Matlab than about mathematics per se.

Comment: If you define all y values and all derivative vectors as np.array, it should work as it is.

Comment: @LutzL could you please provide code for that? What do you mean with the derivative vectors? the f function above?

Comment: Just to point it out explicitly, $y=0$ is the solution of $y''+y+y^3=0$ to the zero initial values. It would be strange if the solver were to get anything different. If you want to test to exactness try $y''+y+y^3=\sin^3t$ with $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$ as that has the exact solution $y(t)=\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to change, depending on how "user friendly" you want to make it. The quick solution is to explicitly use `np.array` for vectors, for the classical example of the physical pendulum $y''+\sin(y)=0$ you could code

```
def f(t, y): return np.array([ y[1], -np.sin(y[0]) ])

y0 = np.array([1.0,0.0])

for h in [0.5, 0.05, 0.005, 0.0005]:
    xv, yv = integrate(method=rk4, f=f, t0=0.0, y0=y0, tend=1.0, h=h)
    print("[ %20.15f, %20.15f]"%(yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]) )
```

gives the output

```
[    0.600232949607472,   -0.754659515900116]
[    0.600085385678949,   -0.754963692069849]
[    0.600085366129492,   -0.754963713951030]
[    0.600085366127465,   -0.754963713953161]
```

correctly gaining 4 digits for every reduction of the step size by 10.

---

If you wanted to remove the `np.array` from the user side, you would have to change the `integrate` function to detect the type of `y0` and if it is not a scalar, redefine initial vector and the input function

```
if y0 is not np.float:
    y0=np.asarray(y0);
    f_=f; f=lambda t,y:np.asarray(f_(t,y));
```

or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But what are y[1] and y[0]? What is in there? And why print yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]? Would that work for the examples given above, if I change the values of the initial values vector y0 accordingly? I wanted a generic method, which works for any given system of ODEs of higher order..

Comment: The input of `f` is a time and a state vector. As the system is 2-dimensional, the state vector has 2 components. // As to the automatic generation of the first order system, matlab has such a procedure, and if I remember right, also the symbolic library `sympy`. But in most cases you will be faster in coding and execution if you code that manually.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: for the first example ode 2nd order I gave above in the question, would this f be appropriate?  def f(t,y): return np.array([ y[1], -y[0]-(y[0])**3 ])

Comment: Yes. And no-one is forbidding you to stay in context, so define `f=lambda t,u: np.array([u[1], -u[0]-u[0]**3])`.

Comment: edited the question, after trying to change the code to what you told me.. I get 0 vectors

Comment: Okay.. Changed the initial values to Y0 = np.array([0.0,1.0]) and I got better values.. Sorry my fault!

Comment: but just a last question.. in Y0, Y0[0] is u(0) and Y0[1] is u'(0) or the other way round?

Comment: Yes, it is the usual convention that `y[k]` is the k-th derivative if there is only one higher-order ODE involved. The only requirement is that the order in state and derivative vector is the same, that is, every derivative component contains the derivative of the corresponding state component.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! 1) Would this solution work, if the ODE involved is: u''''(x) - 7u'''(x) + 4u''(x) + 5u'(x) - 2x = 0?  I mean we tested just with a 2nd order ODE. 2) How to test it for the second example I provided with u1' and u2'? 3) Could you "please" modify your code, so that it is more clear with what you said "Why not staying in context and using f=lambda t,u: np.array([u[1], -u[0]-u[0]**3])"? Thanks in advance, you are saving my life with this!

Comment: The last was just the remark that if the variable in the task is $u$, then you can also name the variable in the code `u`. For the system you just code it as it is, `def f(x,u): u1,u2=u; return np.array([98*u1+198*u2,-99*u1-199*u2]);`. The 4th order equation has likewise `[ u[1],u[2],u[3], 7*u[3]-4*u[2]-5*u[1]+2*x]` in the returned vector.